# Flutter iterate through list of buttons with map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to iterate through a list of very similar buttons but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is since each button will need an onPressed function that passes a single argument.

```
      Column(
        children: buttons
            .map(
              (item) => Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  myButton(item[0], item[2]),
                  myButton(item[1], item[2]),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  MyButton(this.abool, this.onPressed);

  final bool abool;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return RawMaterialButton(
        child:
            Image.asset('images/button.png'),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );
```

So of course I have a problem with storing the different `onPressed` functions in a `List` array. What's the best way to iterate through a list of similar buttons like this in a column?

Comment: What do you currently store in the `buttons` variable?

Comment: @Marcel I want to store the onPressed function.

Comment: Ahh I see. What are the arguments to `myButton`? A label and an `onPressed` callback? And what are the labels on the buttons supposed to be?

Comment: @Marcel I've updated the question with the button function. The `onPressed` should be a function like `(val) => aFunction(val)`. The first item is just like text, a boolean or whatever.

Comment: @Marcel Maybe there's a whole better way to do this? I mean to generate a list of similar buttons with different functions for onPressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension (also called UI-as-code) since Dart 2.3 to generate buttons on the fly right inside the list.

```dart
List<String> labels = ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'kiwi'];
List<VoidCallback> actions = [_buyApple, _doSomething, _downloadData, () => print('Hi')];

...

Column(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
      RaisedButton(
        label: Text(labels[i]),
        onPressed: actions[i],
      ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I don't see how the functions for `_buyFruit` for each button are generated?

Comment: Since as explained in the question, I need different `onPressed` functions for each button. If the functions were all the same I wouldn't have had the problem with storing them in a List array.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect that. Does this approach work for you? If the buttons all look the same, you wouldn't even need the `labels` list

Answer (score 0):

**If the Buttons don't share similar behavior** , you should not have to make the Mybutton class.
you can't make one class for Sign up button and Login button ,each one has different responsibility and behavior .

This class should be used when you have data model (shopItem) for example (and from your code i think this is the case) , and you need (add to cart) functionality for example , this is a case where you have to make addToCartButton and be something like this :

```
class AddToCartButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final ShoptItem item;
  AddToCartButton({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddToCartButtonState createState() => _AddToCartButtonState();
}

class _AddToCartButtonState extends State<AddToCartButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Add to Cart'),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            cartList.add(item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

notice that i've used stateful widget (not necessary ) if there is any kind of state in the button itself like

```
Text(inCart? 'already in cart':'add to cart'),'
```

unless you are using state management like provider ,bloc, etc.

the second notice here (most Important) that i've used cartList which basically a list of ShopItem .

**Now all the buttons have similar functionality** (adding item to the cart) ,but every button should add different item , that can be done in column you're using or the ListView builder which i prefer

*the Column approach:*

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    for( item in itemsList)
      AddToCartButton(item : item);

  ],
```

*ListViewBuilder approach :*

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: itemsList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context,index){
    return AddToCartButton(item : itemsList[index]);
  },
)
```

I hope that can help

Comment: This is the same as the other answer. The functions need to be different, as outlined in the question, they're not the same function with different arguments, that would be very easy to do.

Comment: as i said you should make the myButton class if the buttons dont share similar behavior , if there anything i'm missing please explain